# pycharm pytestrunner PluginManager unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

I have a very simple test script just to learn pytest, tmp.py:

```
def square(x):
    return x*x
def test_square():
    assert square(4) == 16
```

Using Pycharm to run this script, I've configured my project setting such that pytest is used as my default test runner. When I run the above code I get the following error:

```
/Users/mingxiao/webdav_2.7.5/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pycharm/pytestrunner.py -p pytest_teamcity /Users/mingxiao/dev/juggernaut/src/integrations/webDAV/demo/tmp.py "-k test_square"
Testing started at 4:41 PM ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pycharm/pytestrunner.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pycharm/pytestrunner.py", line 20, in main
    _pluginmanager = PluginManager(load=True)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'load'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am running PyCharm 3.0 Professional edition, pytest 2.4.2, and python 2.7.5. It seems that its PyCharm itself that is causing the problem.

Comment: It's PyCharm with no *s* at the end.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears to be an incompatibility between PyCharm and py.test 2.4.x. If you install py.test 2.3.5 (for example, `pip install pytest==2.3.5`) it works fine. I suggest submitting a bug report to JetBrains.

Comment: If PyCharms hasn't fixed it, file an issue at the pytest issue tracker.  It's an easy fix i think.

Answer (score 2):

PyCharm pytest helper does not seem to be compatible with newer pytest.
Until they fix it, replacing it with the contents of your py.test script works just fine.

Helper is located  at `PyCharm.app/helpers/pycharm/pytestrunner.py` (you can see this path when trying to run tests). Just put the output of `` cat `which py.test` `` in it, for me it is:

```
  __requires__ = 'pytest==2.5.1'
  import sys
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      sys.exit(
          load_entry_point('pytest==2.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'py.test')()
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems issue was created in pycharm tracker http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11235

Comment: It is fixed in upcoming version 3.1!

Answer (score 0):

In the PyCharm add pytest to your project by:
Settings --> Project interpreter --> Click on the plus green icon --> search for "pytests" --> Click on the "Install package" button

Rerun, now it should work